# Add third list on dependent dropdown list JS

Tags: javascript, list, dependencies

I'm trying to create a dynamic dependent drop down lists. This code below work fine with 2 dependency and I’m trying to add a third dependency. Have you got any idea ?
For exemple :

Status 1 = offer 1, offer 2, offer 3 , offer 4

Offer 1 = Option 1

Thanks for your help

**UPDATE 11.15.09**

Finally find a solution

```js
$("#street").val([]);
$('#street option').hide();

$("#city").on("change", function() {
  $('#street option')
    .hide() // hide all
    .filter('[value^="' + $(this).val() + '"]') // filter options with required value
    .show(); // and show them

  $("#street").val([]);
})

$("#number").val([]);
$('#number option').hide();

$("#street").on("change", function() {
  $('#number option')
    .hide() // hide all
    .filter('[value^="' + $(this).val() + '"]') // filter options with required value
    .show(); // and show them

  $("#number").val([]);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
City:
<select id="city" name="city">
  <option value="0">Select City</option>
  <option value="1">Manchester</option>
  <option value="2">Leicester</option>
  <option value="3">Londra</option>
</select>
Street:
<select id="street" name="street">
  <option value="1.A">Street A</option>
  <option value="1.B">Street B</option>
  <option value="1.C">Street C</option>
  <option value="2.D">Street D</option>
  <option value="2.E">Street E</option>
  <option value="2.F">Street F</option>
  <option value="3.G">Street G</option>
  <option value="3.H">Street H</option>
</select>
Number:
<select id="number" name="number">
  <option value="1.A">1</option>
  <option value="1.B">2</option>
  <option value="1.C">3</option>
  <option value="2.D">4</option>
  <option value="2.E">5</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the problem with javascript. (no need to use jQuery)

Please try to use updated code below.

**HTML:**

```
<div>
    <select name="select1" id="select1">
      <option value="1" data-sync="1">Status 1</option>
      <option value="2" data-sync="2">Status 2</option>
    </select>
</div>
<div>
    <select name="select2" id="select2">
      <option value="1">offer 1</option>
      <option value="1">offer 2</option>
      <option value="1">offer 3</option>
      <option value="1">offer 4</option>
      <option value="1">offer 5</option>
      <option value="2">offer 6</option>
      <option value="2">offer 7</option>
      <option value="2">offer 8</option>
      <option value="2">offer 9<option>
    </select>
</div>
<div>
  <select name="select3" id="select3">
    <option value="1">option 1</option>
    <option value="2">option 2</option>
    <option value="1">option 3</option>
    <option value="2">option 4</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

**Javascript:**

```
document.getElementById("select1").onchange=function() {
    document.getElementById("select2").value=this.options[this.selectedIndex].getAttribute("data-sync");
        document.getElementById("select3").value=this.options[this.selectedIndex].getAttribute("data-sync");
}
document.getElementById("select1").onchange();
```

Check the running code link below.

http://jsfiddle.net/f97u5nLa/33/

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply, but there is no dependancy in your code. If i select Status 1, i have all the offer, even for status 2.